# How to use SQL Server Compact 3.5 with Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database in my Visual Studio project. When I try to create a Entity Framework model (from database) it only shows SQL Server Compact 4.0. I tried to reinstall 3.5 but that did nothing.

I need to to keep my version at 3.5 because SSIS can only write to a 3.5 file which is where my data is comming from.

Any ideas on how to get Visual Studio to use the 3.5 file?

Answer (score 0):

Create the EDMX in a non web project, or use my SQL Server Toolbox add-in.

Comment: I actually used your add-in to create the 3.5 file because VS was only showing 4.0.

Comment: So, I used the toolbox to create the edmx, but there were no tables in the model. Do I have to add the existing table manually?

Comment: My table was missing the primary key, after I added it I was able to use your toolbox to build the model. Now the issue I have is that when I try to build the controller I get an error that the metadata could not be read.

Comment: My connection string was added to app.config, I moved it to web.config and got past that error. Now I get "could not load the specified metadata resource"